# XORing file with multi-byte key

Tags: python, xor

I'm simply trying to XOR a file with a multi-byte key. The key may vary in length. Returning the following error:

```
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

Here is what I'm working with right now.

```
def xor(data, key):
    l = len(key)

    decoded = ""
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        decoded += chr(ord(data[i]) ^ ord(key[i % l]))
    return decoded

data = bytearray(open('myfile.bin', 'rb').read())

key = '\x2a\x2b\x2c\x5e\x25\x44'
a = xor(data, key)
print a
```

I know I'm missing something simple but can't place it.

Comment: Could you provide a test case (input file + expected output file) -- for testing our answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bytearray` are ... array of *bytes* ... not *char*.

You cannot use `ord()` on a byte. This has no meaning.

Try that instead:

```
def xor(data, key):
    l = len(key)

    decoded = ""
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
            decoded += chr(data[i] ^ ord(key[i % l]))


    return decoded
```

Not very Pythonic ... I probably could have done better. But seems to work at least.

---

**EDIT:** As explained in the comments, it is *not* a good idea to mix bytes and unicode characters.

As you are working with bytes here, your key should have been bytes too. Simplifying the code as a side effet:

```
def xor(data, key):
    l = len(key)
    return bytearray((
        (data[i] ^ key[i % l]) for i in range(0,len(data))
    ))


data = bytearray(open('myfile.bin', 'rb').read())

key = bytearray([0x2a,0x2b,0x2c,0x5e,0x25,0x44])
```

Comment: while this works, i don't think it's a good idea. You shouldn't mix `bytes` and `str` this way! You're xoring bytes with unicode codepoints and returing unicode, that makes no sense. Usually `xor(xor(a, b), b)` should return `a` to be consistent. It would be better for data and key to be both bytes and return bytes.

Comment: @mata You are right. The "key" should have been bytes too. I don't know if this OP could change that though...

Comment: @mata I've edited the answer. I think the last option is more consistent: data are bytes, the key is bytes -- and so is the result.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - yes, that looks better. My solution would have been something in the liene of `xor = lambda value, key: bytes(i^j for i, j in zip(value, itertools.cycle(key)))`

Comment: Thanks @SylvainLeroux, you helped me [here](https://github.com/ctfs/write-ups-2015/tree/master/bsides-vancouver-ctf-2015/forensics/garbage-file)!